# Should there be an Entity Framework Core [inmemory] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I tried to add an [inmemory] tag for [Entity Framework Core's InMemory provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory), but I can't add [inmemory] as [in-memory] already exists (but that tag refers to something else).

I also tried [entity-framework-core-inmemory], but that's too long.

I'm guessing as EF Core adoption widens there will be more questions on InMemory which would probably benefit from a tag, as the name Microsoft have chosen (InMemory) is unhelpfully similar to lots of existing terms and names.

Comment: DO you think that tag would fill the following criteria : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191 . Point 3 specifically, does the InMemoryProvider really make things different enough to have a proper tag ?

Comment: @Walfrat InMemory is definitely a discrete standalone concept, and lots of EF elements do have their own tags, e.g. [dbcontext], so I think it probably is different enough - but I definitely defer to those with more experience on this type of thing. I think normally if new tags are added and not used they then get automatically removed again?

Comment: yes they are, i don't know myself entity framework, but since you have some upvotes seems like things are going well. Maybe you can skip the "core" in the tga's name by the way.